# What are the two bugs in this C code?

Tags: c, debugging, output

```
char * append(char s1[], char s2[]) {

int s1len = strlen(s1);
int s2len = strlen(s2);
int k;
    for(k = 0; k<s2len; k++) {
        s1[k+s1len+1] = s2[k];
    }
return s1;
}
```

It is said that there are two bugs in this code.. Identify them and explain why they are bugs and modify the code to correct them...

The bugs I found is that you can't return arrays and that s2 is not even being modified to be returned in the first place....

Am I wrong? I don't know what the real bugs would be.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `s1[k+s1len+1]`?

Comment: The question what was the real question asked to you??

Comment: You can't return a local array, but `s2` is not a local array. It's a pointer to the argument array.

Comment: what if strlen s2 > strlen s1, bad access.also this part s1[k+s1len+1]

Comment: How do you know s1 has enough memory to append s2 into?

Comment: I don't know what would be wrong with s1[k+s1len+1], it's just setting a value of the array at that index.

Comment: That's not a bug in the function implementation, that's a bug in the caller. This code is essentially equivalent to `strcat`, it can't prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: I just don't understand which 2 bugs my professor wants... :(

Comment: Look at the specification of strcat. Figure what you should fix to make this function conform to the spec.

Comment: sizeof(s1) must be >s2len+s1len

Comment: It was given to assume there was enough space that has been allocated for s1 to store the extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing is you need to know how printf works. If the printf encounters the null character,it stops writing to stdout, so anything after the null character won't show in your output, you can test this by changing any character in a string to null character and then check its output, nothing else will be printed after the null character.

Answer (score 4):

1. `s1[k+s1len+1]` should be `s1[k+s1len]`. Otherwise, you leave `s1`'s trailing null in the middle of the appended string.
2. You need to append a null terminator after appending all the characters of `s2`. You can achieve this automatically by changing the loop end condition to `k <= s2len`.

Look at the two strings `abc` and `defg`:

```
s1 = abc\0
     0123
s2 = defg\0
     01234
s1len = 3
s2len = 4
```

The result you want is:

```
s1 = abcdefg\0
     01234567
```

When `k = 0`, `k+s1len+1 = 4`, so your code was putting the first character of `s2` here:

```
abc\0d
0123 4
```

So the `null` byte was being left in place. When the loop completed, the whole result was:

```
abc\0defg
```

with a `null` in the middle, but no `null` at the end, because the last character you copied was `k = 3`.

Comment: Annnnnnndd, that worked! How did the +1 make such a big impact? I don't understand that, honestly. And how does the condition change if the null character is appended or not? Doesn't it do that anyways regardless?

Comment: Seems strange to return `return s2;` and not `s1`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I actually typed it up incorrectly and then copied it incorrectly. Should be returning s1.

Comment: I've added more explanation to the answer, showing why being off by 1 caused this problem.